# Explain some code [binary trees, nodes]

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree

I have been given a task which involves (emphasis on involves, it's not just making a program that holds data in a tree structure) making a tree structure that holds data but sure how to do so I looked it up.

In the tutorial I'm reading the code the author provided but it assumed you have an understand of C# (it states that but not to what degree, I believe my understanding is below what the author meant).

Code that I'd like explained to me:

```
public class Node<T>
```

Why is there a `<T>` in the above code? What does this mean? What does it do? How does it impact the class (please see full class to gain a further insight). I assume it is linked to the below code?

---

```
private T data;

public Node(T data) : this(data, null) {}
```

Is the above code an overload? What does the colon (:) do to the code?

---

All the code from the class:

```
public class Node<T>
{
        // Private member-variables
        private T data;
        private NodeList<T> neighbors = null;

        public Node() {}
        public Node(T data) : this(data, null) {}
        public Node(T data, NodeList<T> neighbors)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.neighbors = neighbors;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                data = value;
            }
        }

        protected NodeList<T> Neighbors
        {
            get
            {
                return neighbors;
            }
            set
            {
                neighbors = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A general explanation of how the code links in together in the class would be appreciated too but if not I think I'd be able to figure it out.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `<T>` indicates it's a generic class you can pass a type into. For example you can construct an instance of the `Node` class like this:

```
var node = new Node<string>();
```

The compiler then *sees* all instances of `T` as `string`. It allows you to reuse code for multiple different types.

Generics is quite a large subject to cover in a StackOverflow post so I suggest you read up on this. MSDN has a nice guide you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx).

The colon in `public Node(T data) : this(data, null) {}` allows you to chain constructors.

In your case the fact it's calling `this` means the constructor is within the same instance. You'll come across `base` as well which will let you call the constructor in the immediate ancestor of the class.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the link, I'll check it after I've responded to you. By chaining what do you mean sorry? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Chaining means linking them together. The chained constructor will be called first then your constructor body.